# Building .NET Core 1.0 RC2 app on the build server

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've updated my app from DNX, ASP.NET 5 RC1 to ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC2.
Locally it builds and runs fine.

On the build server, I don't have Visual Studio installed, and the build fails with:

> error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I did install the: [.NET Core SDK for Windows](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows).
Trying to install the VS 2015 tooling preview fails with:

[image]

What would be the correct setup to build .NET Core 1.0 RC2 app on the build server without having to install Visual Studio 2015?

Note: The build box (TeamCity 9) builds/runs tests fine for .NET 4.5 and DNX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So without Visual Studio or Web Deploy, my TeamCity build is comprised of 4 builds steps:

```
dotnet restore
dotnet build
dotnet test
dotnet publish -c Release
```

I run [dotnet test on all projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37323364/net-core-1-0-how-to-run-all-tests-in-solution-with-xunit-command-line) with a basic for loop.

Answer (score 3):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/windows-prerequisites#issues

Issues
You may be blocked from installing the .NET Core Tooling Preview 2 for Visual Studio 2015 installer due to a temporary bug. To workaround it, run the installer from the commandline with the `SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1` argument, as you see in the example below.

`DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1`

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It shows the same "I want the full VS 2015" message.

Comment: This workaround doesn't work for the 1.0.1 release of this installer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to **build** the solution now. [Still can't publish though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37395651/cant-publish-asp-net-core-1-0-rc2-application-on-build-server).

I just copied all the new MSBuild stuff to the build server. I copied:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\
```

From my local computer to the build server. That includes the new ***DotNet*** sub-folder, which contains:

```
Microsoft.DotNet.Common.targets
Microsoft.DotNet.Extensions.targets
Microsoft.DotNet.props
Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets
Microsoft.DotNet.targets
Microsoft.DotNet.Tasks.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DotNet.Runtime.dll
Newtonsoft.Json.dll
```

I can *build* the Solution (without the publish arguments) it fails when I try:

MSBuild.exe  Solution.sln **/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:publishprofile=local**

Answer (score 0):

You can build and test you project via the command line - so there is no need to have Visual Studio installed. By using build steps of type "Command Line" you can run: dotnet restore, dotnet build, dotnet test

Here you can find some description how to run that as a build on TFS. It is written for the hosted TFS but works on-premise as well (and is not only meant for azure as the name of the document might imply):
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnetcore-to-azure

For the pubsishing I have used msdeploy with RC1 but have not yet migrated my deployment build. I might document it here when this is done within the next days.