# xUnit run all tests under tests folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, xunit

Is there any way (apart from this  [.NET Core 1.0 - How to run "All tests in Solution" with xUnit command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37323364/net-core-1-0-how-to-run-all-tests-in-solution-with-xunit-command-line)) to run all unit tests using xUnit through VS Code? I have created the following task:

```
    {
        "taskName": "test",
        "args": [
            "./tests/Project1.UnitTests"
        ],
        "isTestCommand": true,
        "showOutput": "always",
    }
```

However I'd like to pass in the args something like `"./tests/*.UnitTests` so that every time I add a new test project the task picks this up. Is that currently possible?