# Dotnet CLI build and test – just run the tests

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, command-line-interface, xunit

```
**\*test*.dll
```

I want use this schema on dotnet cli but I can't found dotnet test documentation nothing.my project file structure is this way [this](https://ibb.co/hVtzqG).

At the moment tests It looking at all the .dll files under the .sln file. but I want just looking tests.dll files

```
dotnet test --no-build "**\*test*.dll" //?? All files in my project
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't such a pattern to filter that for dotnet test, we can only filter tests by **DisplayName** or **FullyQualifiedName** for xUnit, refer to this link for dertails : https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/filter.md

But it can only filter the tests, it cannot exclude other non-test project .dlls.

e.g.

```
dotnet test --filter "FullyQualifiedName=YourNamespace.TestClass1.Test1"
```

Howerever you can try writing PowerShell script to filter the test projects and run the command in the loop. Reference: [Dotnet CLI – running tests from multiple assemblies](https://tpodolak.com/blog/2017/06/07/dotnet-cli-running-tests-from-multiple-assemblies/)

e.g.

```
Get-ChildItem | ? { $_.Name.Contains("Test") } | ForEach-Object { Push-Location; Set-Location $_.Name; dotnet test --no-build; Pop-Location}
```

Also this thread for your reference : https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/705

---

Another workaround is writing a **cmd/bat** script to run the test projects only:

e.g.

```
cd C:\TestProjectPath\A.Tests

dotnet test --no-build

cd C:\TestProjectPath\B.Tests

dotnet test --no-build

cd C:\TestProjectPath\C.Tests

dotnet test --no-build
```

Answer (score 2):

You achieve the same without any script by using `dotnet vstest` with some regular expression with wildcards.

For example:

```
dotnet build --configuration Release
dotnet vstest ./**/*Tests/bin/Release/**/*Tests.dll
```

the first command will generate the Release folder with the dll. The second will run all the test dll that finds matching the pattern.

This works well with xUnit frameworks. Not sure about other frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

In the Path to project(s) enter **/*Test.csproj so it will only run test Test project.